# Call function with another function as argument within class

Tags: c++

I have tried to build code which passes a function to be used within another function. Below is the code I tried, and it works OUTSIDE the function (so if I delete everything related to class Foo, it works), but I have no idea how to get this to work within the class itself. How can I pass one function within the class along? I tried with `this->part1_math_class`, `Foo::part1_math_class` and `part1_math_class`, none worked.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <functional>

int64_t loop(std::string partialMath, std::function<int64_t(std::string)> recurse)
{
    while (partialMath.find("(") != std::string::npos)
    {
        auto posClose = partialMath.find(")");
        auto posOpen = partialMath.rfind("(", posClose);

        std::string sub = partialMath.substr(posOpen + 1, posClose - posOpen - 1);

        int64_t resultInner = loop(sub, recurse);
        partialMath.replace(posOpen, sub.size() + 2, std::to_string(resultInner));
    }

    return recurse(partialMath);
}

int64_t part1_math(std::string math)
{
    return 0;
}

int64_t part2_math(std::string math)
{
    return 1;
}

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() { }
    
    int64_t loop_class(std::string partialMath, std::function<int64_t(std::string)> recurse)
    {
        while (partialMath.find("(") != std::string::npos)
        {
            auto posClose = partialMath.find(")");
            auto posOpen = partialMath.rfind("(", posClose);
    
            std::string sub = partialMath.substr(posOpen + 1, posClose - posOpen - 1);
    
            int64_t resultInner = loop_class(sub, recurse);
            partialMath.replace(posOpen, sub.size() + 2, std::to_string(resultInner));
        }
    
        return recurse(partialMath);
    }
    
    int64_t part1_math_class(std::string math)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    
    int64_t part2_math_class(std::string math)
    {
        return 3;
    }
    
    int64_t runLoop()
    {
        return loop_class("(1 + 2)", Foo::part1_math_class);
    }
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << loop("(1 + 2)", part1_math) << std::endl;  // this one works
  Foo bar;
  std::cout << bar.runLoop() << std::endl;  // this one does not even compile
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to send a member function as a parameter to another function ?

Comment: Yes, but within the same class. I could use some sort of if logic to do the same stuff, but I wanted to just pass along the function (within the same class) to run.

Comment: Why don't you use a lambda? `return loop_class("(1 + 2)", [this](std::string math) { return part1_math_class(math); });` `std::function` can be used with functions as well as functors. In this case, the lambda provides the matching functor (correct signature) and binds (captures) `this` as member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning

```
    int64_t runLoop()
    {
        return loop_class("(1 + 2)", Foo::part1_math_class);
    }
```

`Foo::part1_math_class()` has the matching signature for the `std::function<int64(std::string)>` when called with the correct object.
In this case, `this` would be the pointer to the intended object. Hence, it must be "cheated" somehow into the call.

An easy way is to use a [functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object) instead of a function. A functor is a class which overloads the `operator()` and can act like a function but with additional context.

[std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) arguments can accept functors as well as functions.

The IMHO easiest way to write a functor is a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
    int64_t runLoop()
    {
        return loop_class("(1 + 2)",
          [this](std::string math) { return part1_math_class(math); });
    }
```

`this` is captured. The signature matches as the parameter is compatible and the return type is auto-detected from the lambda's body and matching as well.

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfac3c5818edb46b)

Comment: Nice, that worked exactly as I wanted it to. I really need to read up properly on lambdas on how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

First, to form a member function pointer you need `&Foo::part1_math_class`; note the `&`.

Second, when an n-ary non-static member function pointer is stored in a `std::function`, it acts as an n+1-ary function because it requires an implicit first argument that becomes the `this` pointer. Since your non-static member function is unary, it would be suitable for a binary `std::function`. But your `std::function` is also only unary. Therefore, you cannot use a non-static member function pointer.

Declare `part1_math_class` `static` to make it work.

Comment: And how would I do it with std::bind then? I tried that as well, but couldnt get it to work either.

Comment: That should be a topic of a different question.

Comment: The advantage of `std::function` is that it can be used with functors also. Hence, you can provide additional context by the function members. `this` could be part of this context. Hence, I don't see why you recommend _Declare part1_math_class static to make it work._

Comment: Well, assuming I use member variables within part1_math of the current class, I cannot use a static function (which is the case for my real scenario, I just thought the example would illustrate the issue)

Comment: Then you must do as @Sheff says: Bind the first parameter of your non-static member function to an object. In modern code, the easiest to do that is using a lambda expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can parameterize your functions taking callbacks so that they don't require an `std::function` and can instead get other types of callable objects.

Then, two options are to bind `this` to the member function pointer, or to use a lambda:

```
// ...
template<typename F>
int64_t loop(std::string partialMath, F recurse)
{
    // ...
}

// ...

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() { }
    
    template<typename F>
    int64_t loop_class(std::string partialMath, F recurse)
    {
        // ...
    }
    
    // ...
    
    int64_t runLoop()
    {
        using namespace std::placeholders;
        return loop_class("(1 + 2)", std::bind(&Foo::part1_math_class, this, _1));
    }
    
    int64_t runLoopLambda() {
        return loop_class("(1 + 2)", [this](auto&& ...args) {
            return this->part1_math_class(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        });
    }
};

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `loop_class` a template and then use simple `bind` or lambda. (General, lambda's should be prefered over bind, but in this case I find using bind simpler). For example:

```
int64_t loop_class(std::string partialMath, std::function<int64_t(std::string)> recurse)
{...}
```

or template

```
template <typename F>
int64_t loop_class(std::string partialMath, F recurse)
{...}
```

and then

```
int64_t runLoop()
{
    return loop_class("(1 + 2)",  bind(&Foo::part1_math_class, this, std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

[See live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba16d2916f922339)